# Add all values in array for each ID in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, sum, shift

I have this table:

```
NAME  |12/31/2016|VALUE
AAA   |1/31/2017 |10
AAA   |2/1/2017  |20
AAA   |2/2/2017  |30
AAA   |2/3/2017  |40
AAA   |2/4/2017  |50
NAME  |2/9/2017  |VALUE
BBB   |2/10/2017 |20
BBB   |2/11/2017 |30
BBB   |2/12/2017 |40
BBB   |2/13/2017 |50
BBB   |2/14/2017 |60
```

and this would be my desired output:

```
NAME  |DATE       |VALUE
AAA   |12/31/2016 |150
AAA   |1/31/2017  |140
AAA   |2/1/2017   |120
NAME  |DATE       |VALUE
BBB   |2/9/2017   |200
BBB   |2/10/2017  |180
BBB   |2/11/2017  |150
```

What I want to do is, for each of the valid symbols, (`AAA`, `BBB`) I want to have three rows.

For the first row of each column, I want all the values added,

For example, row 1 value for AAA:

```
10+20+30+40+50 = 150
```

then for row 2 I want to just add from the second value to the last.

For example row 2 value for `AAA`

```
20+30+40+50 = 140
```

and so on same goes for `BBB`.

I want to shift the dates down so that `12/31/2016` would match `AAA`, then get the first three dates for each row.

I currently have this code. but this doesn't do much. it just gives me a bunch of numbers.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use Data::Dumper;

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}

my %cashflow;
my %fields = (
    ID    => 0,
    DATES => 1,
    VALUE => 2,
);

my @total;
my @IDs;
my @uniqueIDs;
my @dates;
my @add;
my $i = 0;
my @values;

my $counter = 3;

open( FILE, "try.CSV" );

while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    chomp( $line );
    my @lineVals = split( /\|/, $line );

    if ( $lineVals[ $fields{ID} ] !~ /^SYMBOL$/i ) {
        push @IDs, $lineVals[ $fields{ID} ];
    }
    @uniqueIDs = uniq( @IDs );

    #push all CASH FLOW AMOUNTS to @cashflow
    if ( looks_like_number( $lineVals[ $fields{VALUE} ] ) ) {
        $lineVals[ $fields{VALUE} ] =~ s/\r//;
        push @total, $lineVals[ $fields{VALUE} ];
    }

    if ( $lineVals[ $fields{DATES} ] =~ /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/ ) {
        $lineVals[ $fields{DATES} ] = sprintf( '%04d%02d%02d', $3, $2, $1 );
    }

    $cashflow{ uc $lineVals[ $fields{ID} ] }{DATES} = $lineVals[ $fields{DATES} ];
    $cashflow{ uc $lineVals[ $fields{ID} ] }{VALUE} = $lineVals[ $fields{VALUE} ];

    foreach my $ID ( @uniqueIDs ) {

        foreach my $symb ( keys %cashflow ) {

            if ( $ID = $symb ) {

                if ( looks_like_number( $lineVals[ $fields{VALUE} ] ) ) {

                    $lineVals[ $fields{VALUE} ] =~ s/\r//;
                    push @total, $lineVals[ $fields{VALUE} ];

                    my $i     = 0;
                    my $grand = 0;

                    foreach my $val ( @total ) {

                        while ( $i < $counter ) {

                            $grand += $val;
                            print "$grand \n";
                            $i++;
                        }

                        shift @total;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

close FILE;
```

I'm really stuck with this. I don't know what to do with the problem.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#uniq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub trim {
    my ($str) = @_;
    s!\A\s+!!, s!\s+\z!! for $str;
    $str
}

my $file = 'try.CSV';    
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$0: $file: $!\n";

my ($group_name, @dates, @values);
my $sum = 0;

my $print_group = sub {
    return if !defined $group_name;
    my $format = "    %-6s|%-11s|%s\n";
    printf $format, 'NAME', 'DATE', 'VALUE';
    for my $date (@dates) {
        printf $format, $group_name, $date, $sum;
        $sum -= shift @values if @values;
    }
};

while (my $line = readline $fh) {
    my ($name, $date, $value) = map trim($_), split /\|/, $line;
    if ($name eq 'NAME') {
        $print_group->();
        $group_name = undef;
        @dates = $date;
        @values = ();
        $sum = 0;
        next;
    }
    $group_name ||= $name;
    push @dates, $date if @dates < 3;
    push @values, $value if @values < 2;
    $sum += $value;
}
$print_group->();
```

---

Let's go over it.

```
sub trim {
    my ($str) = @_;
    s!\A\s+!!, s!\s+\z!! for $str;
    $str
}
```

A helper function for removing leading/trailing whitespace from a string. We're using `!` as the `s` delimiter here because `/` breaks SO's syntax highlighting. Shrug.

```
my $file = 'try.CSV';    
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$0: $file: $!\n";
```

Open our input file. Note: We use a lexical variable (`$fh`) instead of a bareword filehandle, and we use 3-argument open. This is strongly recommended. We also check open's return value and produce a nice error message in case of failure, including both the name of the file that couldn't be opened (`$file`) and the reason for failing (`$!`).

```
my ($group_name, @dates, @values);
my $sum = 0;
```

We set up some state variables that we want to preserve across loop iterations. `$group_name` is the name of the group we're currently processing, `@dates` is the saved dates we've seen so far, `@values` is the saved values we've seen so far. `$sum` is a running sum of all the values in the current group, and it starts at `0`.

```
my $print_group = sub {
    return if !defined $group_name;
    my $format = "    %-6s|%-11s|%s\n";
    printf $format, 'NAME', 'DATE', 'VALUE';
    for my $date (@dates) {
        printf $format, $group_name, $date, $sum;
        $sum -= shift @values if @values;
    }
};
```

A helper function for printing the output for a single group. If `$group_name` isn't set, we haven't processed any input for the current group yet, so we do nothing and return. Otherwise we print a `NAME | DATE | VALUE` header, followed by a row of data for each element in `@dates`. For each `$date` we output the current group name (e.g. `AAA`), `$date`, and the sum of values (all nicely formatted using `printf`). Initially `$sum` is the sum of all group values, but after the first iteration we start subtracting the values from `@values`: If the list of values in the input was `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, ..., then `$sum` is initially `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + ...`, and that's what's printed in the first line of output. After that we subtract `x1`, so the next line gets `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + ... - x1`, which is `x2 + x3 + x4 + ...`. After that we subtract `x2`, so the third row of data gets `x3 + x4 + ...`.

```
while (my $line = readline $fh) {
    my ($name, $date, $value) = map trim($_), split /\|/, $line;
```

Our main loop. We read a line of input, split it on `|`, and trim each field.

```
    if ($name eq 'NAME') {
        $print_group->();
        $group_name = undef;
        @dates = $date;
        @values = ();
        $sum = 0;
        next;
    }
```

If `$name` is `'NAME'`, this is the start of a new group. Print the output for the current group if any (`$print_group->()` does nothing if there is no current group), then reset our state variables back to initial values, except for `@dates`, which is filled with the `$date` value from the header row. Then start the next iteration of the loop because we're done with this line.

```
    $group_name ||= $name;
    push @dates, $date if @dates < 3;
    push @values, $value if @values < 2;
    $sum += $value;
```

If we get here, this line is not the start of a new group. We set `$group_name` if it hasn't been set yet. We add `$date` to our list of saved dates (but we only need 3 dates, so do nothing if we already have 3). We add `$value` to our list of saved values (but we only need 2 of them). Finally we add `$value` to our total `$sum` within the group.

```
}
$print_group->();
```

At the end of the loop we've also just finished processing a group, so we need to call `$print_group` here as well.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. however. this gives me this result: Argument "CASH" isn't numeric in addition (+)
    NAME  |DATE       |VALUE
    SYMBOL|12/31/2016 |900
Argument "CASH"  line 19.
    SYMBOL|1/31/2017  |900
    SYMBOL|2/1/2017   |890

Comment: @shia1717 I'm not sure what you're referring to. There is no `CASH` in your sample data, and line 19 of my code doesn't contain `+`.

Comment: oh sorry, that was VALUE.

Comment: You've lost me. What input data are you using?

Comment: I was using another one. (*facepalm*). Sorry. i tried it again and it worked fine! Many Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using non-standard delimiters for the substitution `s!\A\s+!!, s!\s+\z!!` and why do you have a *reference* to a subroutine instead of an ordinary subroutine?

Comment: @Borodin The delimiters are explained in the post. A named sub would be global, but I want a local function because it closes over other local variables.

Comment: @melpomene: I'm sorry, I should have read your post! I'm not sure what you mean about the subroutine; a regular sub would allow access to the same variables and there's no need for a closure here.

Comment: Yay for O(N) instead of requested O(N^2)

Comment: @Borodin If I don't make it a closure, I have to pass all the variables as arguments every time (`$group_name`, `@dates`, `@values`, `$sum`). That's too much code duplication for my taste.

Comment: @melpomene: But clearly those variables are available to the subroutine anyway by virtue of being declared beforehand. Are you saying that you have a personal rule to *never* access data in a subroutine that isn't either a parameter or a captured variable from a closure?

Comment: @Borodin If they're declared beforehand, that makes the subroutine a closure. I don't understand where you're going with this.

Comment: I'm simply trying to understand why you have `my $print_group = sub { ... }` instead of just `sub print_group { ... }`. Both work just fine without passing the three external lexicals as parameters.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, but in the latter case you have a global sub referring to local variables, which is error prone (e.g. someone could accidentally call the sub before the variables are defined). I could, if I wanted to, wrap a loop around my current code or move it into a separate sub with no changes. If I'd used a named sub, I'd have to convert it to a local sub first or I'd run into the "will not stay shared" error.

Answer (score 2):

This will do as you ask. It reads the whole data file into an array of arrays and manipulates that array before printing it. The blocks are processed backwards from the end so that the other blocks remain in place when the trailing lines are deleted

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line and writes the result to `STDOUT`

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @data = map [ /[^|\s]+/g ], <>;

# Make a list of the indices of all the header rows
my @headers = grep { $data[$_][0] eq 'NAME' } 0 .. $#data;

# Make a list of the indices of the first
# and last lines of all the data blocks
my @blocks = map {
    [
        $headers[$_] + 1,
        $_ == $#headers ? $#data : $headers[$_+1] - 1
    ]
} 0 .. $#headers;

# Shift the second column down
# Replace the col2 header with 'DATE'
#
$data[$_][1] = $data[$_-1][1] for reverse 1 .. $#data;
$data[$_][1] = 'DATE' for @headers;


# Edit each block of data
#
for my $block ( reverse @blocks ) {

    my ( $beg, $end ) = @$block;

    # Calculate the block total
    my $total = 0;
    for ( $beg ... $end ) {
        $total += $data[$_][2];
    }

    # Calculate the first three data values
    for my $i ( $beg .. $beg + 2 ) {
        my $next = $total - $data[$i][2];
        $data[$i][2] = $total;
        $total = $next;
    }

    # Remove everything except those three lines
    splice @data, $beg+3, $end-$beg-2;
}

print join('|', @$_), "\n" for @data;
```

#### output

```
NAME|DATE|VALUE
AAA|12/31/2016|150
AAA|1/31/2017|140
AAA|2/1/2017|120
NAME|DATE|VALUE
BBB|2/9/2017|200
BBB|2/10/2017|180
BBB|2/11/2017|150
```